# Grouping and Counting with XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm trying to evaluate, group and count nodes using XSLT 1.0 and could use a little help.  What I need to do is evalute a node-set and create strings which I then group and count before outputting anything.

Here's my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
    <WIDGETS>
        <ITEM>
            <CODE>FX1</CODE>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <CODE>SP2</CODE>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <CODE>FX1</CODE>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <CODE>P4</CODE>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <CODE>WT</CODE>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <CODE>XQ</CODE>
        </ITEM>
    </WIDGETS>
</DATA>
```

And my stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />      
<xsl:template match="DATA/WIDGETS">     
    <xsl:for-each select="ITEM">
        <xsl:choose> 
            <xsl:when test="CODE = 'FX1'">Performance Series </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="CODE = 'XQ'">Performance Series </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="CODE = 'SP2'">Sports Series </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="CODE = 'P4'">Sports Series </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="CODE = 'WT'">Classic Series </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The current output looks like this

```
Performance Series Sports Series Performance Series Sports Series Classic Series Performance Series
```

What I would like tp produce though is this

```
Performance Series(x3) Sports Series(x2) Classic Series
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to store the first transformation, in which you convert all CODE to their respective series, in a variable and then again processing the variable to count the repeating series:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
    <!-- key declaration to select NEWCODE using its value -->
    <xsl:key name="item" match="NEWCODE" use="."/>

    <xsl:template match="DATA/WIDGETS">
        <!-- variable TEMP, a temporary document containing NEWCODE 
            for every ITEM with respective series as its value -->
        <xsl:variable name="TEMP">
            <xsl:for-each select="ITEM">
                <NEWCODE>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="CODE = 'FX1'">Performance Series </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="CODE = 'XQ'">Performance Series </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="CODE = 'SP2'">Sports Series </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="CODE = 'P4'">Sports Series </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="CODE = 'WT'">Classic Series </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </NEWCODE>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- iterating on every first NEWCODE(of its series) in variable TEMP, 
             and creating the desired string with count of its series --> 
        <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($TEMP)/NEWCODE[count(. | key('item', .)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '(x', count(key('item', .)),') ')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The processing of the variable TEMP is done using **Muenchian's grouping**, which uses `key()` to group elements.

In this answer, an `xsl:key` is declared at the top of the document, which is used later in the `xsl:for-each` to select `NEWCODE` by their values.

The `xsl:for-each` iterates on the first occurrences of `NEWCODE`(first by their value in $TEMP). And inside the `xsl:for-each`, `count(key('item', .))` will count all `NEWCODE` with the value same as the current `NEWCODE` you are iterating on.

Comment: Brilliant - I had the right idea in my head with creating the NEWCODE, but it was the second part I had trouble determining how to do. Thanks!

Comment: any recommended reading on the secondary part - particularly it's the key function portion I'm not understanding.

Comment: @dscl I hope the added explanation helps. You can refer to this to know more about [Muenchian's grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can do this by matching the first item of each class, and transforming it to provide a total count of the items of that class:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="DATA/WIDGETS">     
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ITEM" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ITEM"/>

<xsl:template match="ITEM[CODE = 'FX1' or CODE = 'XQ'][1]">
  <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(following-sibling::ITEM[CODE = 'FX1' or CODE = 'XQ']) + 1"/>
  <xsl:text>Performance Series</xsl:text>
  <xsl:if test="$count > 1">(x<xsl:value-of select="$count"/>)</xsl:if>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ITEM[CODE = 'SP2' or CODE = 'P4'][1]">
  <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(following-sibling::ITEM[CODE = 'SP2' or CODE = 'P4']) + 1"/>
  <xsl:text>Sports Series</xsl:text>
  <xsl:if test="$count > 1">(x<xsl:value-of select="$count"/>)</xsl:if>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ITEM[CODE = 'WT'][1]">
  <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(following-sibling::ITEM[CODE = 'WT']) + 1"/>
  <xsl:text>Classic Series</xsl:text>
  <xsl:if test="$count > 1">(x<xsl:value-of select="$count"/>)</xsl:if>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This does suffer from duplicating parts of some of the selectors, but it feels more idiomatic to me than the other answer.  It also avoids relying on extension funtions, however broadly supported. YMMV.